# Ocultar un textbox en c#

Tags: c#

quisiera saber como se puede ocultar un TextBox y me aparezca cuando seleccione una opción en este caso un RadioButton.
Se trata de un convertidor de tb a kb y viceversa lo que quiero es que cuando ejecute el programa no aparezca el textbox, y que aparezca cuando eliga una de las dos opciones ya sea de Kilo byte a tera byte o viceversa.

Ayúdenme por favor, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Probaste con la propiedad visible?

Comment: Has probado a establecer su propiedad `.Visible` a false?

Comment: en el editor de visual studio en el cuadro inferior derecho vas a ver una ventana con propiedades. Busca la propiedad `visible` y la cambias a `false` o puedes hacerlo con codigo dentro de la funcion de un boton.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que sea un Windows Forms (actualiza tu pregunta si no fuera el caso), tendrás que iniciar tu TextBox a visible=false. 
Hay varias formas de hacer esto, la más sencilla es desde el diseñador (nombreDeTuForm.designer.cs) y añadirle la propiedad

```
this.textBox.Visible = false;
```

también puedes hacerlo haciendo click derecho desde la vista y seleccionando "propiedades".

Puedes añadir una función que compruebe si el botón marcado es el que te interesa, en función de ello mostrar el textbox o no;

```
public void CompruebaVisibilidad()
{
    if(radioButton.Checked==true)
    {
        this.textBox.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.textBox.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Por último tendrás que añadir un evento a tu radioButton que salte cuando se haga click para que se compruebe su visibilidad:

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CompruebaVisibilidad();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

si solo quieres que se muestre despues de selecionar con el radiobutton
puedes cambiar su propiedad visible a false, de esta forma al iniciar el formulario el textbox no se mostrará.

Para hacerlo solo tienes que seleccionarlo y en el apartado comportamiento está la propiedad visible.

Saludos.